# How to add numbers from a string together imported from a file in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def equake_readf(fname):
    datali = open('equakes50f.txt', 'r')
    datali.readline()
    li = [ ]
    for line in datali:
        line = line.split(",")
        num = line[4]
        print(num)
```

I have a function, equake_readf, it opens a file with a list of info about earthquakes. Its formatted by lines:

```
time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag,magType,nst,gap,dmin,rms,net,id,updated,place,type,horizontalError,depthError,magError,magNst,status,locationSource,magSource
2010-07-28T16:12:05.610Z,43.756,-125.815,10,5.2,mwc,193,143.9,,0.93,us,usp000hh0t,2017-08-01T16:34:36.951Z,"off the coast of Oregon",earthquake,,,,,reviewed,us,gcmt
```

from this function i get the numbers each in a new line:

```
5.2
5.1
6
5.9
5.6
5.7
5
5
5.2
5.1
5.4
5.2
5.6
```

I would like to create a list so I can run the list through my next function that calls mean, median, mode. I have already tried creating li =[] and appending to that and converting to a float. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the simplest answer, the very one you mentioned yourself, wouldn't work.

Here's your code with a few improvements

```
import csv

def equake_readf(fname):
    datali = open('equakes50f.txt', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(datali)
    next(reader)
    li = []
    for row in reader:
        num = row[4]
        li.append(float(num))
    return li
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` module:

```
import pandas as pd

def equake_readf(fname):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    return df["mag"].tolist()

li = equake_readf("equakes50f.txt")
print(li)
```

Output will be something like:

```
[5.2, 5.1, 6.0, 5.9]
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to stick with your way, you need to use `readlines()` method like this:

```
def equake_readf(fname):
    datali = open(fname, 'r')
    lines = datali.readlines()
    li = []
    for line in lines[1:]: # [1:] statement deletes the first item which is 'mag' in this case
        columns = line.split(",")
        li.append(columns[4])

    return li
```

Also, you can try list comprehension:

```
def equake_readf(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        ret_list = [line.split(",")[4] for line in f.readlines()[1:]]

    return ret_list
```

All three functions' outputs will be the same.